# anbox modprobe ashmen installed to different lib (128 and not 112)

Tags: anbox

**ashmem_linux:**

```
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-128-generic/updates/
```

**binder_linux.ko:**

```
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-128-generic/updates/
```

**depmod**

```
DKMS: install completed.
l@l:~$ sudo modprobe ashmen_linux
modprobe: FATAL: Module ashmen_linux not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-112-generic
l@l:~$ sudo modprobe binder_linux
l@l:~$ sudo modprobe ashmen_linux
modprobe: FATAL: Module ashmen_linux not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-112-generic
l@l:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not rebooted since a kernel update was installed. You need to reboot the computer so that it will be running the new 4.15.0-128-generic kernel.